# Allow ONLY c++ 11 coding features and style

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a way to **enforce the use of modern c++ 11 features** from the compiler?

We have to start a new project and stay in C++ will benefit us from the use of the our existing tools and libraries, but what is currently hurting us to the death is the abuse of C style coding, raw pointers, C style vectors and all the dangerous C features that are so error prone or produce errors that are really hard to track, you know what i mean.

I read a note about what is bad in C++ today (c++11 and beyond) is the c++ past and the abuse of low level/old features when is not necessary.

I really would like to enforce from the compiler or with other tool the use of c++ 11 features like smart pointers, containers, reference parameters, c++ standard library and not C libraries, etc.

Thank you very much.

***EDIT:*** I thought it is not necessary to clarify the use of code review. etc.  **I just ask if there is or not a tool/mechanism** that filters creating features, or enforce modern safer features/coding practices. All the lose ends we will manage or figure out later. Thank you very much!

Comment: This is a job for code review and to a certain extent, linting. If a developer continually *hurts* you by using the "dangerous" features of C, discipline that developer!

Comment: C++ is an upgraded C. C++11 is a version of C++ that all old C++ is valid, and you can use updated/ new features. It would not make sense to enforce only C++11, because it is built right on top of C++, it does not stand on its own.

Comment: Drop the entire code-base and use a more governed language (maybe C#) ;-(

Comment: You don't have a technical problem. You have a development-process problem. Software tools won't help you. You need a different kind of organisation. Make code reviews an important, organised part of your process.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: Automatic tools CAN SAVE TIME on all development process, including code review/QAS etc...

Comment: @EvanCarslake: C and C++ are considered **different** languages with some common anchestor (K&R, C90 at best). Each has its field of application and non should be considered "obsolete" as "upgraded" implies.

Comment: Do not add C tag for C++ questions!

Comment: @agustin: Not in this case, I'd say. The line between "modern C++" and "legacy C++" is sometimes quite blurry.

Comment: Google c++ coding style/standard used to have a python script for their xml rule file. ie. the script checks code files and whines about non-conforming  code

Comment: @Olaf agreed corrected.

Comment: @zahir, you do realize that most quality C++ programmers hold the google coding standards ion low regard?

Comment: @TLOlczyk I was talking about the system not the standard itself. One can modify rules according to their needs

Answer (score 4):

You might want to take a look at [clang-modernize](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-modernize.html), it can help with some of what you're looking for. In addition running static analysis to help catch bad practices could help identify areas of your codebase in particular need of some attention / modernization. There are a number of such tools associated with clang and MSVC also has its own [static analysis](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182025.aspx) if you're working with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to ensure c++11 features like `auto` variable declarations, using lambda definitions, range based for loops, etc. are used preferred to older techniques are human based code reviews.

Usage of deprecated stuff, like usage of `std::auto_ptr` may be sorted out by warnings already.
But enforcing new way styles might become hard, without having a 2nd pair of experienced eyes looking at the code.

I could think of instrumenting an appropriate static code analysis tool, to detect old style patterns and propose the c++11 standard way to do it, but that's a way too broad topic, and depends on the static analysis tool used.

Comment: And only a human will spot the error in something like 'auto strVector = GetNames();' :)

Answer (score -1):

At the risk of getting downvoted to oblvion.

So you or your "expert" on C++ programming, want to ban certain practices.
Because you know they are bad.

One such practice is using raw pointers.  Shame that there are C++ programmers who not only use pointers very often, but think they are a good thing thing to use. Guys like Herb Sutter, who in a recent talk ( CppCon I think ) said exactly that.

Another practice you mention is using C style vectors. Not a problem since C does not have vectors.

Those are really the only two that you mention. But you do talk about  banning features that cause errors. That can easily be achieved. Instead of issuing your programmers computers. Issue them etch-a sketch's.

Other then that, I would say that your company should hire people who are  real experts, not some guy who read a Herb Schildt book.

PS: I was trying to remember what your post smelled like, now I remember. It smells like one of those deign doc review, where one guy spend half the time arguing about spelling errors in the design docs.

Comment: I know you understand what we want to achieve, developing a codebase as safer as possible and saving some lines of code that reach our code reviewers. Are you sure you can hire "real expert" developers every time you need them at accessible cost? Or even find them? ..Seriously You smell like a person that is not touching the real world ground.